# Недопонимание использования Math.min в коде

Tags: android, kotlin

эксперты. Прохожу бесплатные гугловские курсы по Android и не могу разобраться в строке кода. Прикладываю полный код:

```
    package com.example.android.navigation

import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import androidx.databinding.DataBindingUtil
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
import androidx.navigation.findNavController
import com.example.android.navigation.databinding.FragmentGameBinding

class GameFragment : Fragment() {
    data class Question(
            val text: String,
            val answers: List<String>)

    // The first answer is the correct one.  We randomize the answers before showing the text.
    // All questions must have four answers.  We'd want these to contain references to string
    // resources so we could internationalize. (or better yet, not define the questions in code...)
    private val questions: MutableList<Question> = mutableListOf(
            Question(text = "What is Android Jetpack?",
                    answers = listOf("all of these", "tools", "documentation", "libraries")),
            Question(text = "Base class for Layout?",
                    answers = listOf("ViewGroup", "ViewSet", "ViewCollection", "ViewRoot")),
            Question(text = "Layout for complex Screens?",
                    answers = listOf("ConstraintLayout", "GridLayout", "LinearLayout", "FrameLayout")),
            Question(text = "Pushing structured data into a Layout?",
                    answers = listOf("Data Binding", "Data Pushing", "Set Text", "OnClick")),
            Question(text = "Inflate layout in fragments?",
                    answers = listOf("onCreateView", "onActivityCreated", "onCreateLayout", "onInflateLayout")),
            Question(text = "Build system for Android?",
                    answers = listOf("Gradle", "Graddle", "Grodle", "Groyle")),
            Question(text = "Android vector format?",
                    answers = listOf("VectorDrawable", "AndroidVectorDrawable", "DrawableVector", "AndroidVector")),
            Question(text = "Android Navigation Component?",
                    answers = listOf("NavController", "NavCentral", "NavMaster", "NavSwitcher")),
            Question(text = "Registers app with launcher?",
                    answers = listOf("intent-filter", "app-registry", "launcher-registry", "app-launcher")),
            Question(text = "Mark a layout for Data Binding?",
                    answers = listOf("<layout>", "<binding>", "<data-binding>", "<dbinding>"))
    )

    lateinit var currentQuestion: Question
    lateinit var answers: MutableList<String>
    private var questionIndex = 0
    private val numQuestions = Math.min((questions.size + 1) / 2, 3)

    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
                              savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {

        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        val binding = DataBindingUtil.inflate<FragmentGameBinding>(
                inflater, R.layout.fragment_game, container, false)

        // Shuffles the questions and sets the question index to the first question.
        randomizeQuestions()

        // Bind this fragment class to the layout
        binding.game = this

        // Set the onClickListener for the submitButton
        binding.submitButton.setOnClickListener @Suppress("UNUSED_ANONYMOUS_PARAMETER")
        { view: View ->
            val checkedId = binding.questionRadioGroup.checkedRadioButtonId
            // Do nothing if nothing is checked (id == -1)
            if (-1 != checkedId) {
                var answerIndex = 0
                when (checkedId) {
                    R.id.secondAnswerRadioButton -> answerIndex = 1
                    R.id.thirdAnswerRadioButton -> answerIndex = 2
                    R.id.fourthAnswerRadioButton -> answerIndex = 3
                }
                // The first answer in the original question is always the correct one, so if our
                // answer matches, we have the correct answer.
                if (answers[answerIndex] == currentQuestion.answers[0]) {
                    questionIndex++
                    // Advance to the next question
                    if (questionIndex < numQuestions) {
                        currentQuestion = questions[questionIndex]
                        setQuestion()
                        binding.invalidateAll()
                    } else {
                        view.findNavController().navigate(R.id.action_gameFragment_to_gameWonFragment)
                    }
                } else {
                    view.findNavController().navigate(R.id.action_gameFragment_to_gameOverFragment2)
                }
            }
        }
        return binding.root
    }

    // randomize the questions and set the first question
    private fun randomizeQuestions() {
        questions.shuffle()
        questionIndex = 0
        setQuestion()
    }

    // Sets the question and randomizes the answers.  This only changes the data, not the UI.
    // Calling invalidateAll on the FragmentGameBinding updates the data.
    private fun setQuestion() {
        currentQuestion = questions[questionIndex]
        // randomize the answers into a copy of the array
        answers = currentQuestion.answers.toMutableList()
        // and shuffle them
        answers.shuffle()
        (activity as AppCompatActivity).supportActionBar?.title = getString(R.string.title_android_trivia_question, questionIndex + 1, numQuestions)
    }
}
```

Интересует одна лишь строчка: `private val numQuestions = Math.min((questions.size + 1) / 2, 3)`
Как я понимаю в переменную присваивается минимальное значение из двух чисел. Берется размер списка List(в данном случае 10) и прибавляется к этому числу единица, далее делится всё на 2. Т.е. получается возвращаем минимальное между 5.5 и 3.
Если всё так, то для чего предназначена данная строчка? Почему второе число именно 3? Подскажите пожалуйста.

Comment: смысл Math.min Вы описали верно, но вот какая в этом логика -вопрос к автору кода, похоже что это условие победы, ответить либо на больше чем половину вопросов или если их больше 6 то на 3

Comment: Что-то про 5.5 вряд ли.

Comment: Это ошибки в ответах, их должно быть не больше трех. для списка вопросов меньше 5  - не больше половины (2 и 1 соответственно).